# Is there any ruling on consuming works made by atheists and heretics?

Tags: contemporary-halacha

Is there any ruling on consuming works made by atheists and heretics? Of course, some are just outright blasphemous (works by the likes of Dawkins and Hitchens) and heretical (i.e. Spinoza). I'm inclined to think there's prohibition with the works by these types, perhaps with the exception of instances when it is done to refute and contend with their claims. But there are also atheists and heretics that produce works that do not try to contend with G-d and religion, although one may be inclined to see that their views will inevitably seep into their work to some extent.